# Google Chrome inactivity redirect

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, javascript, kiosk

I have chrome opening in kiosk mode - I added the `--kiosk` flag to the chrome shortcut which works as expected.

We would now like to have the browser re-direct to *www.MyDomain.com* after x minutes of inactivity on any page/tab.

The kiosk allows browsing of our **intranet** and the **internet**. Our issue is we don't want users for example browsing to YouTube (or any other www website) and then walking away. I realise I can use javascript to redirect pages on our local intranet, but what about the internet?

I have tried Kiosk [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban?hl=en) which does exactly what we require but the swipe left/right gestures don't seem to work for page navigation using our Dell s2240's (already contacted the developer via github).

I have also tried [Tab Wrangler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-wrangler/egnjhciaieeiiohknchakcodbpgjnchh?hl=en) which doesn't meet our requirements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this perhaps? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idle-reset/nnaoeblcffjlledmikadmhhfhjpolcjd?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple chrome extension/addon should do the trick: [Idle Reset.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idle-reset/nnaoeblcffjlledmikadmhhfhjpolcjd?hl=en)

Source: Mad Google-fu skills